How to enable screen share permission inside elctron Application
Im working on Secured based browser application using elctron. I have the url that will browse brom the browsers(chrome, edge etc) that will call my desktop application (i.e: Electron application).
The url contains some webrtc based. which asks to enable camera and share screen option. But insde electron application im not getting share screen option.
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, ipcMain, shell, dialog } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const CryptoJS1 = require('./src/crypto-js.min.js')
const CryptoJS= require('crypto-js')


let mainWindow = null;
let mainURL=null;
let parts=null;

if (process.defaultApp) {
    if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
      app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('essc', process.execPath, [path.resolve(process.argv[1])])
      dialog.showErrorBox('Welcome raju', `You arrived from: ${process.argv[1]}`)
    }
  } else {
    app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('essc')
    dialog.showErrorBox('Welcome raju11111', `You arrived from: ${process.argv[1]}`)
    mainURL=process.argv[1];
    parts = mainURL.split("essc://");
    
  }
function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        fullscreen: true,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
    
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html'));
    //mainWindow.loadURL('https://helpdesk.excelindia.com/HelpDesk#/loginpage')
    
    mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
        globalShortcut.unregisterAll();
    });

    // Register global shortcuts
    // Modify these shortcuts as needed
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+C', () => {
        console.log('Copy functionality prevented');
    });
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+V', () => {
        console.log('Paste functionality prevented');
    });
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', () => {
        console.log('Cut functionality prevented');
    });
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+A', () => {
        console.log('Select all functionality prevented');
    });
    globalShortcut.register('PrintScreen', () => {
        console.log('Printscreen functionality prevented');
    });

    // Prevent tab switching
    // Modify tab switching behavior as needed
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Tab', () => {
        console.log('Tab switching functionality prevented');
        // Prevent default behavior
        mainWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({ type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'Tab' });
    });

    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Shift+Tab', () => {
        console.log('Reverse tab switching functionality prevented');
        // Prevent default behavior
        mainWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({ type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'Tab', shift: true });
    });
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
    let decryptedvalue=decrypt(parts[1])
    dialog.showErrorBox('Welcome ramu1111', `You arrived from: ${decryptedvalue}`)
    //let decryptedvalue=decrypt(parts[1])
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://'+decryptedvalue)
    //mainWindow.loadURL('https://helpdesk.excelindia.com/HelpDesk#/loginpage')
   
    app.on('open-url', (event, urlString) => {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of opening the URL

        // Parse the URL
        const urlObject = url.parse(urlString);
        
        // Handle the URL based on the protocol and path
        if (urlObject.protocol === 'essc:') {
            console.log('essc');
            document.getElementById('browser-frame').src = 'https://helpdesk.excelindia.com/HelpDesk#/loginpage';
            //document.getElementById('browser-frame').src = url;
            // Example: Handle the 'open' command
            if (urlObject.pathname === '/open') {
                // Handle 'open' command
                dialog.showErrorBox('Info', 'Open command received');
            } else {
                dialog.showErrorBox('Error', 'Unknown command');
            }
        }
    });

    // Register second-instance event to handle multiple instances
    app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
        if (mainWindow) {
            if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
            mainWindow.focus();
        }

        dialog.showErrorBox('Welcome Back-nagarjun', `You arrived from: ${commandLine.pop().slice(0, -1)}`);
    });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
});

app.on('will-quit', () => {
    globalShortcut.unregisterAll();
});



